# How to pass an array to Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to pass an array to Firestore using the code below. The problem is the array is always empty in Firestore. If I pass an array manually, it works. If I console.log the array it outputs, it's not empty.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    ...
    finally {
        ...
        console.log(photoUrlArray) // THIS OUTPUTS THE ARRAY

        collectionRef.add({
            field1: someData,  THIS GETS POSTED
            photos: photoUrlArray,    THIS DOESN'T
        })
    }
}
```

If manually post an array, it works.

```
collectionRef.add({
    field1: someData,  
    photos: ["url1,jpg","url2.png", "url3.wepb"]  THIS WORKS
})
```

I realise I've very probably missed something completely obvious. Can anyone see what the error is, please?

The output of console.log(photoArray) is:

```
[]
0: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/i/t2-dev-9.appspot.com/o/photo2.jpeg?alt=media&token=82e3bd7d-a77a-4045-af71-1a7851bddd7c"
1: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/i/t2-dev-9.appspot.com/o/photo.jpeg?alt=media&token=c71f2fbe-ca64-4189-9403-4d24f1433d77"
```

length: 2

EDIT: HERE'S THE BASIC VERSION OF THE ENTIRE COMPONENT.
The component takes a multiple selection of images from the input, cycles through them and uploads them to Firebase Storage, and pushes the storage URL to the 'photoArray' array'. How do I post photoArray or the contents thereof, to Firestore?

```
export default function AddPost() {
    
    const fileInput = useRef();
    const photoArray = [];

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        let fileArray = fileInput.current.files;
        for (let i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
            handleUpload(fileArray[i]);
        }

        console.log(photoArray); // OUTPUTS THE ARRAY
        const collectionRef = useFireStore.collection('posts');
        collectionRef.add({
            field1: someData,   // WORKS
            field2: someMoreData,    // WORKS
            photos: photoArray,    // DOESN'T
        })
    }

    function handleUpload() {
        
        const storageRef = useStorage.ref()
        const fileRef = storageRef.child(file.name)

        fileRef.put(file).then(() => {
            fileRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
                photoArray.push(url)
            });
       })

    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="file" ref={fileInput}/>
        </form>
    )

}
```

Cheers, Matt

Comment: Can you add where ```var photoUrlArray``` comes into scope? At what point do you instantiate this variable? Does it get modified after it is added to the function scope?

Comment: Hello, the photoUrlArray variable is instantiated in the container function and then accessed by both the handleUpload and handleSubmit functions within the container. The reason I put a console.log in the 'finally{}' section of code above was to check that the photoUrlArray variable does actually contain the correct data just prior to doing the 'collectionRef.add', and it does.

Comment: It would help if you provide a [complete minimal code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that doesn't work the way you expect.  Anyone should be able to run that code to reproduce the result that you observe (also show those results so we can confirm).  Without showing exactly what you're doing to build the array, anything could be going wrong that we can't see.

Comment: The array is not populated when you console log it. It is populated later, and the console shows the latest value. You can verify this by doing something like JSON.stringify on the array and logging that string.

Comment: Thanks Stratubas, you're right, it's empty. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Functional react components are what they sound like: functions. You define a constant in the function body. This will be redeclared on every execution of the function (rerender). To make the value of photoArray persistent across renders, you need to tell react that it is part of the state. Use the useState Hook for this

Comment: Hi Maurice, of course, I thought it didn't look right. I've moved the 'const photoArray = []' inside the handleUpload function (I believe you shouldn't push to a state array) and then am trying 'setMyPhotoArray(photoArray)' - but because setState is asynchronous I'm still getting an empty array. I'd normally use a useEffect to update the state, with it listening for changes to 'photoArray' but this causes an Invalid Hook Call in this code arrangement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some (untested) code.

Look how `handleUpload` now returns a promise, so that you can wait for it to finish before continuing.

```
export default function AddPost() {

    const fileInput = useRef();
    const photoArray = [];

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let fileArray = fileInput.current.files;
        const uploadTasks = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
            uploadTasks.push(handleUpload(fileArray[i]));
        }
        Promise.all(uploadTasks).then(() => {
            console.log(photoArray); // OUTPUTS THE ARRAY
            const collectionRef = useFireStore.collection('posts');
            collectionRef.add({
                field1: someData,   // WORKS
                field2: someMoreData,    // WORKS
                photos: photoArray,    // SHOULD WORK NOW!
            });
        });
    }

    function handleUpload() {

        const storageRef = useStorage.ref();
        const fileRef = storageRef.child(file.name);

        return fileRef.put(file).then(() => {
            return fileRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
                photoArray.push(url);
            });
        });

    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="file" ref={fileInput} />
        </form>
    );

}
```

The order of the photos will most likely be wrong, since they're all uploaded in parallel and their URLs are added when their respective uploads are completed. I'm leaving you to find a way to fix it if you need to.

I also recommend that you use `async` / `await` instead of `then()` whenever possible.

Comment: Hi Stratubas. That works perfectly, many many sincere thanks! I will refactor to use async and await too.  The order of the photos is not a concern at the moment - one issue at a time! Thanks again - Matt

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your photo URL's are long, so Firesore has some limitation,
Could you check your Firebase Logs and see if you get a limitation error?

Something like this
INVALID_ARGUMENT: The value of property "xxxx" is longer than 1048487 bytes., null))

Comment: Hello Armen, thanks for your reply. Please see the comments above - the array is actually empty even though it console.logs. That's why nothing is being sent to Firestore. Trying to work out why the array is empty